# Soft keyboard issue

Tags: android

I'm facing a very strange problem related to the soft keyboard in my application and I don't know even where I could start to fix it. I have a text field where the user may input samething. The soft keyboard on my device has in the bottom left a button "BPMF" which pressed changes the keys on the keyboard into simplified chinese (I guess) . In the bottom left there is now a key called "CANG" which pressed changes again the keys. Again there is a bottom left button called "STROKE" whic can be pressed to change the keys again. After that in the left bottom there is a button calle "HW" which pressed exist my activity to the previous one and causes my head aches . So a sequence of "BPMF" - "CANG" - "STROKE" -"HW"  has the effect of closing my activity.
This problem manifests itself only on a Samsung GT-I9000 device . 
If anyone faced such an issue or has any idea please let me know.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the only thing I can suggest is that there may be a clue in the log?  Have you looked?